# copying a file to another created folder

Tags: vba

I'm using VBA and with it I create a folder which name is based on today's' date. Then I need to copy a file from another folder to this newly created folder. I was able to create the folder but I'm stuck in copying the file since the name changes every day depending on the date and is a daily routine I run. Thanks.

Here is the code, the idea is to check if a file is in some location and then copy that file to another folder with name based on today's date(which will change every day).

```
Sub Check_IfFile()
Dim fso As Object
Dim Path As String
Dim d As String

Path = "C:\Archive\"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FolderExists("C:\INVENTORY") Then
  MsgBox "File is in, good to go"
  d = Format(Date, "mmddyyyy")
  If Len(Dir(Path & d, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir (Path & d)
Else
   MsgBox "File is not present"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I see you're missing an instruction to perform the actual file copy, but it's unclear what the problem/question is. Have you reviewed the [methods of FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object#methods)? Also you seem to be using "file" and "folder" interchangeably, but they are two very different things - that's not helping clarify either.

Comment: Are you sure you dont want to be checking to see if `Path & d` exists? right now, you are just checking for `Path` existing... and "file is in" and "file is not present" looks like it should be "folder is in" and "folder is not present" - please clarify what you are trying to do if you need more help.

Comment: I create  Path  & d, what i want to do is copy the file from Inventory to the folder created in Path & d, but that name is going to check every day.

Comment: @ Mathieu you are right sorry I forgot, It would be something like:  FileCopy "C:\INVENTORY\MyFile.xlsx", "C:\Archive\(Path & d)\MyFile.xlsx" The issue is that part of the destination folder (the new folder created that I don't know to handle it). Thanks